# entering datas of php page to database

Tags: php, sql

I have a php form with two text boxes and i want to enter the text box values into the database. I have created the table (with two columns namely webmeasurementsuite id and webmeasurements id) I used the following syntax for creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE `radio` (

`webmeasurementsuite id` INT NOT NULL,
`webmeasurements id` INT NOT NULL

);
```

Utilising the tutorial in the following link, I wrote the php coding but unfortunately the datas are not getting entered into the database. I am getting an error in the insert sql syntax. I checked it but i am not able to trace out the error.Can anyone correct me? I got the coding from http://www.webune.com/forums/php-how-to-enter-data-into-database-with-php-scripts.html
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(webmeasurementsuite id,webmeasurements id) values

('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['webmeasurementsuite

id']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['webmeasurements id']))."')";
echo$sql;
My error is as follows:
INSERT INTO radio(webmeasurementsuite id,webmeasurements id) values ('','')ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id,webmeasurements id) values ('','')' at line 1

Comment: what is the mysql error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your table names have a space in them, you have to always surround them in backticks. Try this for your query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(`webmeasurementsuite id`,`webmeasurements id`) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['webmeasurementsuite id']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['webmeasurements id']))."')";
```

Looking at your pastebin, it looks like you have forgotten to close your input tags:

```
<input TYPE="text" name="webmeasurementsuite id"
```